# Angular 2 RouterStateSnapshot not returning correct url

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

I'm trying to get the redirect after login working based on the documentation from angular.
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#teach-authguard-to-authenticate

I got basically the same setup albeit that some filenames are different.

The problem is that when i log the RouterStateSnapshot url in the authGuard,
it wil always output the first route from app-routing.module.ts ('/countries') instead of e.g. /countries/france/34

authGuard

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    let url = state.url;
    console.log(state); // always outputs first route from app-routing.module.ts ('/countries')
    return this.checkLogin(url);
}

checkLogin(url: string): boolean {
    if (this.userService.isLoggedIn()) {
       return true;
    }
    this.userService.redirectUrl = url;
    console.log(this.userService.redirectUrl);

    // not logged in so redirect to login page
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    return false;
 }
```

App routing module

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'countries', pathMatch: 'full', canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
    { path: 'login', loadChildren: './authentication/authentication.module#AuthenticationModule' },
    { path: 'countries', loadChildren: './countries/countries.module#CountriesModule'},
    ...
];
```

Country routing module

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: CountriesComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: ':name/:id', component: CountryComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] }
];
```

Hope someone can help

Answer (score 1):

you are using same `AuthGuard` for all the paths, hence you are seeing that result, you can either create different Auth guards for different routes or have some logic to identify when the same  `canActivate` is called.

Hope this helps!!